# XML to "Key Value" Scheme

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using C#.
I have the following XML file:

```
<MyItems count="2">
<MyItem itemId="1234">
   <MyItem itemId="12344">
        <!--Same fields like any another MyItem, can be more then one element like that--->
   </MyItem>
<Field id="1">1234</Field>
<Field id="2">My Item 1 Text</Field>
<Field id="3">
  <ListValues>
    <ListValue itemDisplayName="Item P1">Item P1</ListValue>
  </ListValues>
</Field>
<Field id="4"/>
<Field id="5">
  <ItemRef id="xyz">Test Reference</ItemRef>
  <ItemRef id="xyzw">Test Reference2</ItemRef>
</Field>
</MyItem>
<MyItem itemId="1235">
    <MyItem itemId="12355">
        <!--Same fields like any another MyItem, can be more then one element like that--->
    </MyItem>
<Field id="1">1235</Field>
<Field id="2">My Item 2 Text  </Field>
<Field id="3">
  <ListValues>
    <ListValue itemDisplayName="Item P2">Item P2</ListValue>
  </ListValues>
</Field>
<Field id="4"/>
<Field id="5">
  <ItemRef id="xyz">Test Reference</ItemRef>
  <ItemRef id="xyzw">Test Reference2</ItemRef>
</Field>
</MyItem>
<Metadata>
 <MyItemFieldDef>
    <ItemFieldDef id="1" aliasName="Item_ID" />
    <ItemFieldDef id="2" aliasName="Item_Data0" />
    <ItemFieldDef id="3" aliasName="Item_Data1" />
    <ItemFieldDef id="4" aliasName="Item_Data2" />
    <ItemFieldDef id="5" aliasName="Item_Data3" />
    <!--ItemFieldDef 6 etc... -->
  </MyItemFieldDef>
</Metadata>
</MyItems>
```

The xml file scheme: Items, and then for each item i have the fields (each field with field id) and the field defnition in the `<Metdadata>`.
I want to convert the XML to format of "Key-Value" like the following example:

```
 <ex:MyItems xmlns:ex="http://bla.com">
 <ex:MyItem>
      <ex:MyItem>
             <ex:Item_ID>12344</ex:Item_ID>
      </ex:MyItem>
   <ex:Item_ID>1234</ex:Item_ID>
   <ex:Item_Data0>My Item 1 Text</ex:Item_Text>
   <ex:Item_Data1>
     <ex:Item>Item P1</ex:Item>
   </ex:Item_Data1>
   <ex:Item_Data2 />
   <ex:Item_Data3>
     <ex:Item>Test Reference</ex:Item>
     <ex:Item>Test Reference2</ex:Item>
   </ex:Item_Data3>
   <!-- Item_Data4.... -->
   </ex:MyItem>
<ex:MyItem>
  <ex:MyItem>
        <ex:Item_ID>12355</ex:Item_ID>
  </ex:MyItem>
  <ex:Item_ID>1235</ex:Item_ID>
  <ex:Item_Data0>My Item 2 Text </ex:Item_Text>
  <ex:Item_Data1>
    <ex:Item>Item P2</ex:Item>
  </ex:Item_Data1>
  <ex:Item_Data2 />
  <ex:Item_Data3>
     <ex:Item>Test Reference</ex:Item>
     <ex:Item>Test Reference2</ex:Item>
   </ex:Item_Data3>
  <!-- Item_Data4.... -->
  </ex:MyItem>
</ex:MyItems>
```

I'm looking for the best/easy way to make the convert from the first xml file format to the second xml file format.
The reason: the second xml file format is "readable".
I'm have been tried with `XmlDocument` but its take a long time.
There is another way to do that? maybe with `Serallize/Deserallize` ?
Thanks a lot!!

*`<ListValue>` can to be with more then one value

**Edit:** 
1. Add ItemRef Element.
2. Add MyItem element inside MyItem Element

Comment: ListValues node always contains single value?

Comment: Hi, no.. its can to contain more then one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code with Linq to Xml:

```
var inputXml = XElement.Load("input.xml");

var dict = inputXml.Element("Metadata")
    .Element("MyItemFieldDef")
    .Elements("ItemFieldDef")
    .ToDictionary(elem => elem.Attribute("id").Value,
        elem => elem.Attribute("aliasName").Value);

XNamespace ns = "http://bla.com";

var outputXml = new XElement(ns + "MyItems",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ex", ns),
    inputXml.Elements("MyItem")
        .Select(item => new XElement(ns + "MyItem",
            item.Elements("MyItem")
                .Select(myItem =>
                    new XElement(ns + "MyItem",
                        new XElement(ns + "Item_ID", myItem.FirstAttribute.Value))
                ),
            item.Elements("Field")
                .Select(field =>
                {
                    if (field.HasElements)
                        return new XElement(ns + dict[field.Attribute("id").Value],
                            field.Descendants().Where(desc => !desc.HasElements)
                                .Select(desc => new XElement(ns + "Item", desc.Value)));
                    else
                        return new XElement(ns + dict[field.Attribute("id").Value],
                            field.Value);
                }))));

outputXml.Save("output.xml");
```

You mentioned a long time. Probably xml size is large. So I used a `Dictionary`, which provides a quick search.

Comment: WOWWWWWWWWWW!!! you save my life!! Thank you very very  much (x100000)..Best answer ever:)

Comment: if i have element like that: <Reference id="1">Reference Text</Reference> how can i "take" it?

Comment: Pertov, its can deal with any element?

Comment: @CSharpBeginner - Yes, it processes any elements inside `Field` nodes.

Comment: awesome..Thank you very much again!

Comment: can you help me again? I'm tried to deal with senario that i have <MyItem> inside <MyItem> element, i edited my question now

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with `XmlDocument`. Easiest way to do this is to deserialize the incoming XML file into a C# class and map it to another C# object that you can serialize back into XML.

Microsoft actually provides a tool that has the capability of generating a class from XML called [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx). You can use it as follows:

```
xsd.exe /c filename
```

There are more options if you want to specify the class name, namespace, etc.

Once you've got the classes generated for the XML, you can deserialize the class using [XMLSerializer.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize(v=vs.110).aspx). Same thing in reverse for the output class. Also, you can write your own logic for mapping from first object to the next, or use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

**Editing to add link to another SO post with additional info**

Here is [another popular SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document?rq=1) about deserializing XML. If you don't want to use the `xsd.exe` tool, you can create the classes yourself and tell the serializer how to work with it using attributes. Also, there is an [online tool](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) where you can paste in some XML and generate the corresponding C# object.

Comment: Hi, i have now the class. how can i make the convert? I cannot use open sources.. :(